# NSIS - InstallOptions - Skip validation on back button

Tags: installation, nsis, packaging

I am developing an NSIS package for one the products. I have a custom page for gathering SQL Server login credentials. On this page, clicking next must validate the given inputs (whether it connects to the server with given credentials). **This works fine.**

**Problem:**

If I press back button on this page, it is still validating the input; which I do not want. I could not find any way out to skip the validation on clicking back button.

Any suggestions in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

We can specify two function names while calling the page custom command. One to show the page and one for validating which is called as leave page.

```
Page custom ShowDatabasePage LeaveDatabasePage
```

In the leave function, we can do all the validation. If the validation fails just call abort and the work is done. Leave function is called only when the next button is clicked.